# Reg: Jmeter Reporting and configuration

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-5.0

I am doing performance testing for E commerce site. I want to checkout with Credit card. I able to checkout using Jmeter but I am not getting different transaction ID for the orders which was placed while passing the step up users the performance testing using j meter because different transaction ID is generated once the order is placed.

Is there any other way to achieve this scenario?

I have another question related to the above.

I am doing performance testing for 250 users. I want report in following manner.

For 50 users what will be the average time to load the home page, category page, shopping cart?

For 100 users what will be the average time to load the home page, category page, shopping cart?

For 150 users what will be the average time to load the home page, category page, shopping cart?

For 200 users what will be the average time to load the home page, category page, shopping cart?

For 250 users what will be the average time to load the home page, category page, shopping cart?

and so on..............

Please help me on above queries. It will really helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, I tried using Response time Vs Threads graph and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Merge Results](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) plugin which allows aggregating several tests execution and combine into a single file applying prefixes so you will be able to distinguish executions.

So you will be able to compare different test runs either using this plugin directly or generating a [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of the combined .jtl file.

You can install Merge Results plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

An easier option might be going for [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) JMeter test results analysis solution, you can upload test run results there and get them compared in a fancy web interface.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it for reporting.